# npm deprecated warning for packages not in package.json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying to set up a work folder for [Exercism JavaScript tutorial](https://exercism.io/tracks/javascript) and when I run `npm install` command, I get the message below

> npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
>   npm WARN deprecated kleur@2.0.2: Please upgrade to kleur@3 or migrate to 'ansi-colors' if you prefer the old syntax. Visit [https://github.com/lukeed/kleur/releases/tag/v3.0.0\](https://github.com/lukeed/kleur/releases/tag/v3.0.0%5C) for migration path(s).

When I looked through my package.json file, there is no CircularJSON or kleur so I am wondering why I get the warning and the packages in there are not installed by npm. Here's the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "exercism-javascript",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Exercism exercises in Javascript.",
  "author": "Katrina Owen",
  "private": true,
  "repository": {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github.com/exercism/javascript"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
      "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
      "babel-jest": "^21.2.0",
      "babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend": "^1.1.2",
      "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
      "eslint": "^5.6.0",
      "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^13.1.0",
      "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
      "jest": "^23.6.0"
  },
  "jest": {
      "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "package.json"
    ]
 },
 "babel": {
      "presets": [
       [
          "env",
      {
      "targets": [
        {
          "node": "current"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
],
"plugins": [
  [
    "babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend",
    {
      "globals": [
        "Error"
      ]
    }
  ],
      [
        "transform-regenerator"
      ]
    ]
  },
"scripts": {
"test": "jest --no-cache ./*",
"watch": "jest --no-cache --watch ./*",
"lint": "eslint .",
"lint-test": "eslint . && jest --no-cache ./* "
},
"eslintConfig": {
"parser": "babel-eslint",
"parserOptions": {
  "ecmaVersion": 7,
  "sourceType": "module"
},
"env": {
  "es6": true,
  "node": true,
  "jest": true
},
"extends": "airbnb-base",
"rules": {
  "import/no-unresolved": "off",
  "import/extensions": "off",
  "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
  "import/no-default-export": "off"
  }
},
"license": "MIT"
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Probably it is a dependency of one of the dependencies. Just upgrade kleur and install flatted, and it should work fine.

Comment: Successfully installed both kleur and flatted but I still can't install the other packages just by running npm install. I get the same error as before but with the add line `npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '.../registry.npmjs.org/b'`

Comment: Try an `npm list | grep -B10 circular-json`.  This will find references to circular-json in your npm dependencies list (with the previous 10 lines before the reference included, which is useful if you are trying to dig through where it is being pulled in from.